# Synchronizing all threads in a grid in Metal

Tags: multithreading, macos, synchronization, gpgpu, metal

I am trying to write a norm or a squared length function for an n-sized vector in Metal. To do this, I planned on having every thread square each element, then elect one thread to sum all elements.

Here is my current kernel:

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
#include <metal_compute>
using namespace metal;

kernel void length_squared(const device float *x [[ buffer(0) ]],
                           device float *s [[ buffer(1) ]],
                           device float *out [[ buffer(2) ]],
                           uint gid [[ thread_position_in_grid ]],
                           uint numElements [[ threads_per_grid ]])
{
    s[gid] = x[gid];// * x[gid];
    simdgroup_barrier(mem_flags::mem_none);
    if(gid == 0){
        for(uint i = 0; i < numElements; i++){
            *out += s[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this code does not compile, for "Use of Undeclared Identifier `simdgroup_barrier`". The method is documented in the [Metal Shading Language Specification](https://developer.apple.com/metal/metal-shading-language-specification.pdf#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014364).

Has anyone encountered this? or know how to synchronize all threads across a grid? `threadgroup_barrier` does not achieve total synchronization for me.

Am I approaching this problem incorrectly? What is the best way to synchronize this operation?

Comment: `simdgroup_barrier` is currently only available on iOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A SIMD group is smaller than a threadgroup, so that synchronization won't work.

Instead, you'll want to use a [parallel reduction](http://www.drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/parallel-pattern-7-reduce/222000718) to sum up the values in parallel. [Here](https://github.com/mateuszbuda/GPUExample/blob/master/GPUExample/kernel.metal) is some Metal code I found.

Though, if you don't mind a single thread doing all the summing, you can run a separate kernel with just one thread to do the sum. Of course, this can be very slow.